# EF 4.2 Code First, how to map with fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, fluent-interface

(Since i have a database predefined i can't let EF recreate it).

This the mapping i use now (works but i want to rewrite using fluent api):

```
public class League
{        
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid LeagueId { get; set; }
    ....
    #region References

    public virtual ICollection<News> News { get; set; } 

    #endregion
}

public class News
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid NewsId { get; set; }
    public Guid LeagueId { get; set; }
    ....
    #region References

    [ForeignKey("LeagueId")]
    public virtual League League { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Now, how can i map this using the fluent API?

**Update**
Wrote this and it works, but is there a simpler version?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<League>().HasMany(x => x.News).WithRequired(y => y.League).HasForeignKey(c => c.LeagueId);
```

**Update 2**
I added those missing from the classes. But the problem is that if i leave it at that and try it, it fails. I need to specify a key somewhere.I can't let EF create the database and it refuses to just operate with tables.

Comment: The simpler version is to do nothing and let conventions create the relationship. With Fluent API your Update is the answer. BTW: You have hidden a bit too much in your `....` to answer your question properly. Where is the `News` property in the `League` class and where is `LeagueId` in your `News` class? It's only clear with your Update now.

Comment: Updated with the missing information. Problem is that EF doesn't create just the tables. It want's access to the entire database which it can't have.

Comment: What is the question? I'm lost after update 2.

Comment: Your Update 2 is really very unclear. What does "*...it fails.*" mean? And why do you think you need to specify a key? EF will detect `News.NewsId` and `League.LeagueId` as primary key properties, you don't need to specify it. What exceptions do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at this article for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/184133/Using-Entity-Framework-4-1-Code-First-with-an-exis
The base part, is that you should remove default db initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);
```

And this should prevent EF from trying to change your db or throw errors. It will just try to work with what you give it.